# androidでエクセルデータ読み込みたい

Tags: android, java, excel

androidでエクセルデータ読み込みや書き込みができるようにしたい色々と調べてはいるのですが、情報が少なく困っております。
どなたか詳しい方、もしくは詳しく書かれているサイトをご存知の方がいれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家SOに、直接問題が起こっている内容の質問と解決例があります。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999846/writing-to-excel-file-with-apache-poi-in-android-project

JavaでExcelのデータを扱うにはApache POIを使うのが良いでしょう。
エクセルも、xlsやxlsxと拡張子が異なると必要なライブラリが異なります。
https://poi.apache.org/

Apache POIに関してなら情報がネット上にたくさん見つかるでしょう。